# Looking for R's way of doing Stata's svy tabulate with "tab" argument

Tags: r, stata, standard-error, survey, aggregation

Stata's `svy` command allows to get standard error estimates from two way contingency tables and the `tab(varname)` option makes it easy to indicate which variable is the total when obtaining proportions, as the documentation [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/svysvytabulatetwoway.pdf) puts it:

> tab(varname) specifies that counts be cell totals of this variable and
> that proportions (or percentages) be relative to (that is, weighted
> by) this variable. For example, if this variable denotes income, the
> cell “counts” are instead totals of income for each cell, and the cell
> proportions are proportions of income for each cell

Following the previous command, a coworker made this calculation, from which he then obtains the SE by making some calculations on the `e(V)` (variance matrix) object from this table.

[image]

In R, using the survey package I can get the mean by groups and afterwards calculate the proportions of those means by their size and get to the same stata output for the proportions, but I'm having a lot of trouble obtaining the SE from said proportions. Note that the SE from the following image is from the mean and not the proportions, which is what i need.

[image]

So, how do I get the SE of the proportion estimation of an "aggregated" variable in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the statistical issue: you can't just divide the standard errors by the same denominator that divides the estimates, because the denominator is (in general) random and correlated with the numerators.  You need a proper multivariate delta-method calculation.

In R, transformations of the output of a `survey` function are done with `svycontrast`. If I've understood your description correctly, you want `svytotal` rather than `svymean`

```
> library(survey)
> data(api)
> dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
> 
> (totals<-svyby(~enroll,~stype,design=dstrat,svytotal,covmat=TRUE))
  stype    enroll       se
E     E 1842584.3 72581.33
H     H  997128.5 69239.40
M     M  847464.7 55502.96
> 
> svycontrast(totals, list(quote(E/(E+H+M)), quote(H/(E+H+M)), quote(M/(E+H+M))))
       nlcon     SE
[1,] 0.49973 0.0155
[2,] 0.27043 0.0153
[3,] 0.22984 0.0132
```

matching Stata's

```
. svy: tabulate stype, tab(enroll) se
(running tabulate on estimation sample)

Number of strata   =         3                  Number of obs     =        200
Number of PSUs     =       200                  Population size   =      6,194
                                                Design df         =        197

----------------------------------
    stype | proportion          se
----------+-----------------------
        E |      .4997       .0155
        H |      .2704       .0153
        M |      .2298       .0132
          | 
    Total |          1            
----------------------------------
  Tabulated variable:  enroll

  Key:  proportion  =  cell proportion
        se          =  linearized standard error of cell proportion
```

Update: the original post didn't match the Stata output because I forgot to declare the finite population correction in Stata

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative response, I got to the same results as my coworker's stata output.